# 'Required parameter {0} not set'.format(identifier))

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, django-models, heroku-postgres

I'm setting up my AWS for my static files. Basically, when user upload a picture it will directly stored the pictures on my AWS S3. I've done all the procedures, but it gives me an error saying Value error at //profile/ and Required parameter name not set. On my local machine it works, but it wasn't working when I deploy it.

I tried to restart my database then migrate it to heroku command but still get the same error

```py
models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete =models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    update = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

views.py
def profile(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'u_form':u_form,
        'p_form':p_form
    }
    return render(request,'users/profile.html',context)

settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME= os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

I expect the functionality will be the same as my local,because on my local I can load my picture and see the url of AWS, but when I deploy it gives me an error.

Comment: Please show the full error message and traceback. You've omitted the part which tells you which identifier was not defined.

Comment: That's all the error message i get but it also gives me an error during template rendering and it highlights my <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}"> on my base.html

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME are correctly set in the remote environment. Check that those are passed to Django and **for testing purpose only**, try to output them on some log